# Accessing Jenkins plugin static files in java

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm new to Jenkins plugin development.

I want to write a plugin that would spit out a report for weekly build activity.

To make life easy, I would like to read a template file and just fill in the data.
However, I can't find the path to the template file through java in the jenkins plugin I'm developing.

I know the path to the file would be ${JENKINS_CONTEXT_PATH}/plugin/pluginName/template.file
But I was more hoping I could access file "locally" not through the http.

Also, I'm just working off the jenkins plugin "hello-world" example. So if I need to extends other "Extensions" please let me know.

The file structure is roughly as follows:

```
foo.hpi
 +- META-INF
 |   +- MANIFEST.MF
 +- WEB-INF
 |   +- classes
 |   +- lib
 +- template.file
```

And I'm trying to read the file from the perform() method

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `hudson.init.impl.InitialUserContent` class from the Jenkins core [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/981b2ea9fe18f2250cc5c33888de2539fd1cb285/core/src/main/java/hudson/init/impl/InitialUserContent.java#L45) you'll find a good example of how to write files to the file system under the Jenkins home directory. You'll see the key to finding the correct path is leveraging:

```
jenkins.model.Jenkins.getInstance().getRootDir();
```

Now, I haven't tried this myself, but I think it's safe to assume if you can write files, you can also read them. I hope this helps.